# Server 18.04 LTS no updates available for server B, but system A sees available updates at logon

Tags: 18.04, server, updates

I have two Dell Poweredge servers, each running server 18.04.3 LTS  Server A's kernel is 5.3.0-26-generic; Server B's kernel is 4.15.0-74-generic.

Each is nearly installation default plus similar Samba and NFS configurations.  I start them every morning within seconds of each other and log on.  A shows updates available fairly often, and many of them are security updates.  B has been showing zero package updates and zero security updates since mid-December 2019.  Apt-get update results are consistent with the logon display count.

The only thing I messed with in December was the addition of a couple of lines to /etc/exports

I cannot use Livepatch because the servers run backup cycles for other machines on the LAN shortly after boot and shut down.  If there are updates, I defer starting the backup scripts until the updates are done.  That way, a shutdown does not occur during an update.  With Livepatch, I could never be sure.

Have there really been NO updates for 4.15.0-74 since mid-December?  If so, how can I check for myself in the future without asking again here?

Comment: Thanks, but after digging around a bit on how to set up the proposed repository, I find directory /etc/apt/preferences.d is empty, so I don't believe that's the case.

Comment: Sorry the 5.3 kernel only very recently moved from 'proposed' to 'main' so my prior comment was *out-of-date*. I checked before leaving my comment on a 18.04 box (fully-upgraded) but my mirror was *six hours behind* (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) thus my comment was. Apologies 5.3 is production/stable.